# Unable to link directly to WMV video file

Tags: sharepoint, wmv

I have a wmv video hosted in SharePoint.  I've created a Content Editor web part with a bit of custom content and I've placed a simple link to the video `<a href="http://mysite/video.wmv" target="_blank">`Click to view`</a>`.

There is really nothing special going on here.  Some users can click on the link and the video opens in their default video player.  Other users see a range of different errors/prompts.  Some users are prompted for their network credentials and others receive a generic "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage.

The same problems occur if I create a generic HTML web page (outside of SharePoint) and have users try to launch the video.

I am trying to avoid embedding the video in the HTML and just have users link directly to the video itself.

Has anyone encountered this issue and do you have any suggestions for making this work?

Comment: Posting some of the error messages and an example of a WMV's URL would probably be helpful.

Comment: It's already in there in the question.  The URL is EXTREMELY simple and as I've posted in the first paragraph.  Clicking on the link works perfectly for me.  The error is the generic "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".  Perhaps "generic" is the wrong word to use.  It is the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a combination of browser issues and file security.

People are being asked for their network credentials because the file itself is not "public"; it requires authentication to be read, or appears to do so from your description. Different browsers will display different messages when attempting to authenticate for the file.

Additionally, the default player for a browser may not be set or the browser may not allow passoff to third party programs, both of which will generate different messages for different browsers. *This will always be an issue for hot-linked videos*, and there's nothing you can do about it except use some guaranteed playback platform that all consuming browsers must have installed, such as Flash or Silverlight. That comes with issues all on its own, but such is the nature of the online world.

Comment: The users that are being prompted are already "owners" of the SharePoint instance.  It seems odd that they would still be asked for credentials.  However, it's certainly something that I'm going to look into.

As for "hot linking", it sounds like I may be out of luck.  It's too bad because people want to be able to send an email with a direct link to the video instead of a webpage with an embedded video.

Comment: @Alexander Voglund: Regarding the security issues: some browsers don't work well with integrated security and require credentials from the user every time; if the user is using IE but is on an untrusted domain other than the Sharepoint instance's domain, it's entirely likely that they'll need to provide credentials as well. I suggest if you want to hot-link rather than embed, that you tell users to right-click/save-as to download the video as a file, and then open it in their favorite media player.